# Rewriting the code without use of GOTO

Tags: c#

This is a code automatically converted from VB 6.0 to C#.net
What is a safe and correct way to get rid of that `GOTO` statement?

```
public bool IsDirty(bool checkChildrenInd)
{
    bool result = false;
    //Determine if this object is 'dirty', or has been updated since it was created.

    if (Parent.NewInd)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (backup == null)
    {
        goto CheckChildren; //Check any child lists
    }

    if (!String.Equals(MissingDataValue, backup.MissingDataValue))
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (!String.Equals(PreviewDataValue, backup.PreviewDataValue))
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (FieldOption != backup.FieldOption)
    {
        return true;
    }

CheckChildren:
    if (!checkChildrenInd)
    {
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is all? checkChildren will always return false. The whole thing could be rewritten as `public bool IsDirty(bool checkChildrenInd){ return Parent.NewId || backup != null)`

Comment: I agree with Martijn: it seems like "Check any child lists" is not actually checking any child lists whatsoever.

Comment: yes that's all. The PATTERN is always like the method above. Now for some other classes in the code I may have so much more things to check after the (if backup == null) and before GOTO ... and also so much more stuff to check inside the GOTO section as well...but the pattern is like this.

Comment: @Martijn : well how about those IFs for MissingDataValue in String.Equals? aren't we missing them with your code? how?

Comment: They all return true. There isn't much choise there. By the way, I might refactor this to its negation, `IsClean`. returning `true` on something that seems "good" feels more natural than returning `true` on something that seems "bad".

Comment: @BDotA If you wish to work on the pattern and not on this particular instance, I recommend leaving comments like `// do something` in the places where your code might (or not) do something. (Just make sure that the "do something" has no side-effects to the existing instructions... otherwise it's required, for the refactor.)

Comment: @Martijn: the original code can return `false` even if `backup != null`, depending on the backup fields checks, your rewritten version will always return `true` in such case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimal amount of changes to get rid of the `goto` is:

```
public bool IsDirty(bool checkChildrenInd) {
    bool result = false;
    //Determine if this object is 'dirty', or has been updated since it was created.
    if (Parent.NewInd) {
        return true;
    }
    if (backup != null) {
        if (!String.Equals(MissingDataValue, backup.MissingDataValue)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!String.Equals(PreviewDataValue, backup.PreviewDataValue)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (FieldOption != backup.FieldOption) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (!checkChildrenInd) {
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or if you want some refactoring:

```
public bool IsDirty(bool checkChildrenInd) {
    //Determine if this object is 'dirty', or has been updated since it was created.
    return Parent.NewInd
        || backup != null && CheckBackup()
        || checkChildrenInd && CheckChildren();
}

protected bool CheckBackup() {
    return !String.Equals(MissingDataValue, backup.MissingDataValue)
        || !String.Equals(PreviewDataValue, backup.PreviewDataValue)
        || FieldOption != backup.FieldOption;
}

protected bool CheckChildren() {
    return false; // or delegate, when there are any children
}
```

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: FIXED

This *specific* instance can be rewritten as

```
public bool IsDirty(bool checkChildrenInd) {
  return ! (  Parent.NewId ||
              backup == null ||
              String.Equals(MissingDataValue, backup.MissingDataValue) ||
              String.Equals(PreviewDataValue, backup.PreviewDataValue) ||
              FieldOption == backup.FieldOption );
}
```

if this pattern is always the same, but there may be other conditions as you note in the comments, I note that CheckChildren

- Takes a parameter which is also the function parameter
- returns on all code paths
- result is never assigned to before the `goto` statement

If this is always true, you can factor it out. replace the CheckChildren label with a function:

```
private bool CheckChildren(bool checkChildrenInd){
    bool result = false;
    if (!checkChildrenInd)
    {
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and the `goto CheckChildren;` with `return CheckChildren(checkChildrenInd);`

if `result` *is* possibly set to true before the goto statement, you will need to pass result as a variable to the funcion too (and include it in the signature).

Comment: Thanks. Just one last question:  How about those IFs for MissingDataValue in String.Equals? aren't we missing them with your code? how?

Comment: The only path that returns false is if Parent.FirstId is false (otherwise it would have returned true) and backup == null. All other paths return true.

Comment: No, you're right. It falls through to the goto label, and if all checks return false, it returns result, which is initialised as false and never changed. Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Martijn: sorry, but this is completely flawed -- first, you inverted the result for `Parent.NewInd`, you return `false` where the original returned `true` -- then if `MissingDataValue` is clean, but `PreviewDataValue` is dirty, you still return `false` instead of `true`, because the code then never checks `PreviewDataValue` -- last, you should call `CheckChildren()` in place of `goto` AND at the end...

Comment: @Martijn: You tried to negate the condition to `return ! IsClean();`. But in that case the **correct** expression would look like: `return ! ( ! Parent.NewId && ( backup == null || String.Equals(MissingDataValue, backup.MissingDataValue) && String.Equals(PreviewDataValue, backup.PreviewDataValue) && FieldOption == backup.FieldOption ) );`. Be careful with the logic inversions.